# The formula for the CMB Damping Tail makes no sense

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, bao

The formula for the Damping Tail in the CMB BAO analysis generally has the form:
$$\mathcal{D}(k)=\int_{0}^{\eta_0}\dot\tau \exp\left\{-\left[\frac {k}{k_D(\eta)} \right]^2\right\}\mathrm d\eta $$I can’t make sense of this. $\dot\tau$ is the Thompson (Differential) Opacity; the product of electron density, cross section and scale factor.$$\dot\tau(\eta)=n_e\sigma_Ta$$At η = 0 (t = 0), the density is infinite and the scale factor is zero.  How are we supposed to perform this integration when the Thompson Opacity is so obviously indeterminate at the limit?

Comment: Isn’t there supposed to be a factor of $e^{-\tau}$ in the integral? I think it would make the integrand go to zero at $\eta=0$. BTW, does the dot mean $d/d\eta$? I am figuring that $a\sim t^{1/2}\sim\eta$, $n_e\sim a^{-3}\sim\eta^{-3}$, $\dot{\tau}\sim\eta^{-2}$, and $\tau\sim\eta^{-1}$.

Comment: Eqn (12) in https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9609079 has the $e^{-\tau}$.

Comment: You are correct that the Visibility Function would be integratable from 0, but Eqn (6) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9512139.pdf seems to contradict Hu.  Any idea which one is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I’m not familiar with any of this physics and happy to leave it to those who are. Just two lines below (6) your reference talks about “the visibility function - the combination $\dot{\tau}e^{-\tau}$” which is confusing. Could $(k/k_D(\eta))^2$ possibly be a way to write $\tau$?